# Get keycloak Server logs

Tags: configuration, keycloak

We deployed keycloak server 4.6.0.Final for authentication for our web application How can i configure to get server logs? I cannot find any logs from server.log or Audit.log files. Do I need to configure any place to show the keycloak server log details.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When starting the Keycloak instance you can pass an environment variables to set log level for Keycloak.

```
docker run -e KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG jboss/keycloak
```

For the Kubernetes Deployment:

Add the following env variable to Kuberenetes deployment manifest.

```
keycloak:
  extraEnv: |
    - name: KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL
      value: DEBUG
    - name: WILDFLY_LOGLEVEL
      value: DEBUG
```

More informations : https://github.com/devsu/docker-keycloak/blob/master/server/README.md

Answer (score 22):

If you are looking for latest **>=18 version**. The new environment variable is:

```
KC_LOG_LEVEL=<level>
```

The possible levels mentioned here: [Keycloak 18 Logging](https://www.keycloak.org/server/logging)

**FATAL** - critical failures / complete inability to serve requests of any kind.

**ERROR** - significant error or problem leading to the inability to process requests.

**WARN** - A non-critical error or problem that may not require immediate correction.

**INFO** - Keycloak lifecycle events or important information. Low frequency.

**DEBUG** - More detailed information for debugging purposes, including e.g. database logs. Higher frequency.

**TRACE** - Most detailed debugging information. Very high frequency.

**ALL** - Special level for all log messages

**OFF** - Special level to turn logging off entirely (not recommended)

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation specifying the environment variable, https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config?options-filter=config

Comment: Thanks man! I didnt manage to find in in docs...., where to see all variables for docker ?

Comment: Thanks @Doug for sharing the link. I looked many times in this page. But this is the first time when I expand the options and I see the container env params... It's so silly that I overlooked so many times this page. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 16):

**Specify log level**

There are two environment variables available to control the log level for Keycloak:

- `KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL`: Specify log level for Keycloak (optional, default is INFO)
- `ROOT_LOGLEVEL`: Specify log level for underlying container (optional, default is INFO)

Supported log levels are `ALL`, `DEBUG`, `ERROR`, `FATAL`, `INFO`, `OFF`, `TRACE` and `WARN`.

Log level can also be changed at runtime, for example (assuming docker exec access):

```
./keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command='/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:change-log-level(level=DEBUG)'
./keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command='/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:change-root-log-level(level=DEBUG)'
./keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --command='/subsystem=logging/logger=org.keycloak:write-attribute(name=level,value=DEBUG)'
```

The content is taken from [jboss/keycloak - Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak).

Comment: what if we want to show multiple log level? for example to show only DEBUG and ERROR

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker logs  <logfile.txt> to write docker container log as a custom.
Look at : https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/