# Get keycloak events logs

Tags: kubernetes, logging, keycloak, bitnami

We are using [Keycloak packaged by Bitnami](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/keycloak/#installing-the-chart) for our user authentication deployed by Kubernetes. Their document suggests that we can change the log level using

```
    extraEnvVars:
      - name: KEYCLOAK_LOG_LEVEL
        value: DEBUG
```

However, we want to change only the event log level. There is also one runtime solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060682/get-keycloak-server-logs) but it's not suitable for the production environment when using Kubernetes and pods changes.

Keykloack offers this feature, but I'm looking for a solution that allows us to change the **event package log level** using the Keycloak packaged by Bitnami.